# Can I use Vec<> to pass multiple accounts into an anchor program?

Tags: anchor, account

I'm writing an escrow program for multiple assets in one swap. I was trying an effective way to input token mint & token accounts. So I tried using Vec<> as following but it poped up the following error:

[image: trial_1]

Is there a solution to Vec<> error or an effective way to input multiple accounts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can only use the `remaining_accounts` functionality for adding a variable length number of accounts.

From one of the [misc code examples](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/698426033052781988cd7980249726501ae08bdc/tests/misc/tests/misc/misc.ts#L47-L51) in the anchor repo, this is how you can add a vector of remaining accounts with the ts library.

```
    await program.state.rpc.remainingAccounts({
      remainingAccounts: [
        { pubkey: misc2Program.programId, isWritable: false, isSigner: false },
      ],
    });
```

You can access them inside the program function with

```
ctx.remaining_accounts
```

Comment: so is `remaining_accounts` an array?

Comment: It's an array of account infos https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/0.6.0/anchor_lang/struct.Context.html

Comment: so if i have to access one of the accounts, it will be like this:

`ctx.remaining_accounts[0].key()`

Comment: yes, this should compile fine. Don't forget to validate the accounts though