# Handling multiple accounts

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, account

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the best way (even better, trying to fully understand a way) to handle multiple accounts (both client(js / ts) and program(anchor/rust) side).
If I want to call a method from my program and send multiple accounts for it to handle, is there a way to do it without using "remaining_accounts"? If yes, how could it be done? If not, how could "remaining_accounts" be properly used (I'm finding it quite confusing at the moment)?
Also, how could both ways be handled, if possible, on the program side?

Comment: Could you provide some context on where `remain_accounts` is from?

Comment: I was looking at possible solutions, and found this one (amongst a few other examples referring the same): https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/633/can-i-use-vec-to-pass-multiple-accounts-into-an-anchor-program?rq=1
However, every search that I did regarding this, seems somehow confusing. Therefore, I was looking for a more straight forward solution (if possible) or, last case scenario, understand this one.

Comment: I actually just found this: https://medium.com/@Arrivant_/gaming-applications-anchor-a89e37aeb5ad
Will have a deeper look at it and see what I can extract =) (at first, it looks like a long thread on anchor "remaining_accounts" which can be quite useful)

Comment: Come back when you're done, and post an answer to your own question with what you learned!

Comment: @steveluscher, forgot about this.. :( will post a possible answer in a min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to find a suitable solution to use remaining_accounts.
Below is an example on how to iterate through the remaining_accounts, deserialize and change a variable on the account, and serialize it back.

```
pub fn some_function(ctx:Context<SomeContext>, ammount_to_change: u64) -> Result<()>
    {   
        for account in ctx.remaining_accounts.iter() {
    
            let _account_key = account.key();
            let mut data = account.try_borrow_mut_data()?;
    
            let mut account_to_write = BaseAccount::try_deserialize(&mut data.as_ref()).expect("Error Deserializing Data");
    
            account_to_write.var_to_change += ammount_to_change;
           
            account_to_write.try_serialize(&mut data.as_mut())?;
    
        }
        Ok(())
    }
```

The call on the TS side, could be something like

```
const someOutput = await program.methods.someFunction(new anchor.BN('insert ammount here')).accounts({
        }).remainingAccounts([{pubkey: yourPDA, isSigner: false, isWritable: true}]).rpc();
```